# Why each time after creating component I have reference to previous data?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have component that gets data from service by event message:

```
this.objectDetailsSubscription = this.eventService.subscribe(
      EventsChannels.OBJECT_DETAILS,
      semantic => {
        this.layer = this.layerSemanticService.getObjectSemantic(semantic);
      }
    );
```

Where service is:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class LayersSemanticService {
  getObjectSemantic(semantic: LayerItemGeneric): ObjectInformationCustom {
    this.semantic = semantic;
    this.configuration = this.getConfigurationSemantic(semantic.layerIdCommon);

    return {
      buttons: this.getButtons(this.configuration),
    }

  }

    getButtons(configuration: LayerSemanticConfig) {
    configuration.tools = configuration.tools || [];
    configuration.tools.push(EButtonTypes.Pin);
    return configuration.tools; 
  }
}
```

In child component I pass buttons as Input():

```
  *ngFor="let btn of buttons"
```

I have tried to reset variable:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.layer = <ObjectInformationCustom>{};
}
```

No effect

Comment: Seems service stores statement `this.configuration`

Comment: what you have written in getConfigurationSemantic() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are singletons by default (when decorated with `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`, as yours is).

This means that there is one instance that lives in memory for the lifetime of the application. So the state that exists within the service will be the same for all components that are injected with the service, until that state changes.

If the state shouldn't exist beyond the lifetime of a component, then store that state in the component. If it needs to be stored and updated in the service, then update it in the service.

It is possible to configure component-level services by setting them as `providers` in the `@Component()` decorator. This approach needs to be used with caution, though, as it could get confusing.